# C# Linq and Regexing non-unicode

Tags: c#, regex, linq, unicode

I am writing a program that will take data from an AS400 and need to read the first line of the text to determine where the file goes. The data from the AS400 has a lot of nonprintable characters in it.

Here is my working code:

```
//LINQ to read first line and find what I need
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(as400file);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    //Regex the AS400 garbage out of there...
    string replaced = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", String.Empty);
    /*  ^ = not
    *  \u0000 - \u007F is the first 127 chars of UTF-8
    *  So this replaces all non ascii chars with an empty string
    */

    //Rest of program code
}
```

However I really want just the first line of the file and not every line. I couldn't seem to think of a way to get just the first line and I'm not that experienced with linq. Any pointers or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var line = File.ReadAllLines(as400file).First(line => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(line));
string replaced = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", String.Empty);
```

Is... that all you wanted?

Comment: I think this is what I want however sometimes the first line is blank due to formatting from the AS400.
Do I just simply add a where statement to it?
var line = File.ReadAllLines(as400file).First().Where(line != null);

Comment: @moonbeam: First can take a lambda, so I'd make it `.First(line => !line.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)`

Comment: I don't mind taking the first line even if it contains a lambda because I will just regex it out. However there is no option for line.IsNullOrWhiteSpace. Is using where better in this case?

Comment: @moonbeam: A lambda is an anonymous function. It's what you use to decide what the first line is. It's like doing a where first, but more efficient. You can use a different comparison instead of .IsNullOrWhitespace since that may be a more recent addition, but what matters is that using a lambda in .First makes .Where unneeded.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be better for me to not use Linq because I'm just simply reading a file and only want the first readable line. Does it matter which route I go?

Comment: You can easily use another solution, but you'll need to make sure you manage a stream safely (not a problem) and do the filtering separately. An empty line is more likely to be an empty string than a null. Again, you don't have to do it my way, and it could be inefficient if the file is large, but in terms of simplicity, I don't think you can go wrong.

Comment: I tried your code above and it's still not working for me. Says I cannot use ! with method group...

Comment: Updated the answer... but you shouldn't expect SO to always just give you perfect code. Google things if they aren't working. Not all of us can compile code in our minds.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, It will read a single line from the file.

```
string line;

using (var file = new StreamReader(as400file))
{
    line = file.ReadLine();
}

string replaced = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to Alex's answer, you could use a StreamReader to get just the first line:

```
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(as400File))
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    string replaced = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", String.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alex's help here is my working code:

```
//LINQ to read first line and find what I need
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(testfile).First(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line));
//Regex the AS400 garbage out of there...
string replaced = Regex.Replace(lines, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", String.Empty);
/*  ^ = not
 *  \u0000 - \u007F is the first 127 chars of UTF-8
 *  So this replaces all non ascii chars with an empty string
 */
```